# How can I Fail a WebTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, webtest

I'm using Microsoft WebTest and want to be able to do something similar to NUnit's `Assert.Fail()`. The best i have come up with is to `throw new webTestException()` but this shows in the test results as an `Error` rather than a `Failure`.

Other than reflecting on the `WebTest` to set a private member variable to indicate the failure, is there something I've missed?

EDIT: I have also used the `Assert.Fail()` method, but this still shows up as an error rather than a failure when used from within WebTest, and the `Outcome` property is read-only (has no public setter).

EDIT: well now I'm really stumped. I used reflection to set the `Outcome` property to Failed but the test *still* passes!

Here's the code that sets the Oucome to failed:

```
public static class WebTestExtensions
{
    public static void Fail(this WebTest test)
    {
        var method = test.GetType().GetMethod("set_Outcome", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        method.Invoke(test, new object[] {Outcome.Fail});
    }
}
```

and here's the code that I'm trying to fail:

```
    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        this.Fail();
        yield return new WebTestRequest("http://google.com");
    }
```

`Outcome` is getting set to `Oucome.Fail` but apparently the WebTest framework doesn't really use this to determine test pass/fail results.

Answer (score 3):

Set the [Outcome property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.webtest.outcome.aspx) to *Fail*:

```
Outcome = Outcome.Fail;
```

There's also an [`Assert.Fail()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.fail.aspx) in the *Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework* assembly.

Comment: Should have been clearer... I had already tried both of these. (edited question to reflect this)

Comment: [Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0] Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTest.set_Outcome(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Outcome value) is public

Comment: Not according to the dll I'm using. Oucome is a public getter, but there's no public setter. I used reflection to cal the set_Outcome (which is private) but it still has no effect on the test result (i.e. it till does not Fail)

Answer (score 1):

The Outcome property will set the public at vsts 2010 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You make a test always fail by adding a validation rule that always fails. For example, you could write a fail validation rule like this:

```
public class FailValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override void Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Then attach the new validation rule you your webtest's ValidateResponse event, like so:

```
public class CodedWebTest : WebTest
{
    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("http://www.google.com");
        FailValidationRule failValidation = new FailValidationRule();
        request1.ValidateResponse += new EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs>(failValidation.Validate);
        yield return request1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that would work in declarative tests (as well as coded) is:

- write a Validation Rule that fails when a certain Context Parameter (e.g. 'FAIL') is present in the Context
- when you want to trigger the failure, set the Context Parameter and call WebTest.Stop()
- add the Validation Rule as a WebTest-level rule (not request-level) so that it runs on all requests

I think that's as concise as it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm working with VB.net, but I also tried to set the outcome to fail before finding out it does not work (which brought me here).

I finally managed to do it by just throwing an exception :

```
Public Overrides Sub PostRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PostRequestEventArgs)

    If YourTest = True Then

        Throw New WebTestException("My test Failed")

    End If

    MyBase.PostRequest(sender, e)

  End Sub
```

I know this topic is old but I hope it helps someone anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of Outcome in the PostWebTest event handler.